# Combining two dataframes using buffer in geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have two dataframes (not exact data but similar):
df1:

| Lon | Lat | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4.44 | 61.41 | 2021-04-28 00:00:00 |
| 4.48 | 62.45 | 2021-04-28 00:02:00 |
| 4.51 | 61.48 | 2021-04-28 00:06:00 |
| 4.47 | 62.46 | 2021-04-28 00:08:00 |
| 4.44 | 61.41 | 2021-04-28 00:10:00 |
| 4.40 | 62.48 | 2021-04-28 00:12:00 |
| 4.51 | 61.44 | 2021-04-28 00:16:00 |
| 4.47 | 62.49 | 2021-04-28 00:18:00 |

df2

| Lon | Lat | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4.34 | 61.41 | 2021-04-28 00:00:00 |
| 4.38 | 62.45 | 2021-04-28 00:02:00 |
| 4.31 | 61.48 | 2021-04-28 00:06:00 |
| 4.17 | 62.46 | 2021-04-28 00:08:00 |
| 4.34 | 61.41 | 2021-04-28 00:10:00 |
| 4.30 | 62.48 | 2021-04-28 00:12:00 |
| 4.21 | 61.44 | 2021-04-28 00:16:00 |
| 4.47 | 62.49 | 2021-04-28 00:18:00 |

There are other columns as well but my question relates to these columns.
so I want to combine the two dataframes per min within a radius of 100m for every observation in  df1.

Ive done something similar with only one dataframe, where for every observation in the data frame I joined all the observations within the 100m radius.

```
for name, group in df.groupby(['timestamp']):
        buf = group.copy()
        buf['geometry'] = buf.geometry.buffer(100)
        points_within = gpd.sjoin(group, buf,   op = 'within')
```

I need to do something similar but with two dataframes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- there's not much within 100m in the sample dataset.  Increasing distance mean more `sjoin()`
- using **GeoPandas** capability with CRS and `buffer()`. It's import that a UTM geometry is used for distances.  Hence projection to UTM and back to EPSG:4326
- have shown output dataframe plus a [plotly mapbox](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-layers/) as both markers and the geojson including the buffer

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely, json
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Lon": [4.44, 4.48, 4.51, 4.47, 4.44, 4.4, 4.51, 4.47],
        "Lat": [61.41, 62.45, 61.48, 62.46, 61.41, 62.48, 61.44, 62.49],
        "Timestamp": [
            "2021-04-28 00:00:00",
            "2021-04-28 00:02:00",
            "2021-04-28 00:06:00",
            "2021-04-28 00:08:00",
            "2021-04-28 00:10:00",
            "2021-04-28 00:12:00",
            "2021-04-28 00:16:00",
            "2021-04-28 00:18:00",
        ],
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Lon": [4.34, 4.38, 4.31, 4.17, 4.34, 4.3, 4.21, 4.47],
        "Lat": [61.41, 62.45, 61.48, 62.46, 61.41, 62.48, 61.44, 62.49],
        "Timestamp": [
            "2021-04-28 00:00:00",
            "2021-04-28 00:02:00",
            "2021-04-28 00:06:00",
            "2021-04-28 00:08:00",
            "2021-04-28 00:10:00",
            "2021-04-28 00:12:00",
            "2021-04-28 00:16:00",
            "2021-04-28 00:18:00",
        ],
    }
)

MIN_DIST = 10**2

gdf1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=df1.loc[:, ["Lon", "Lat"]]
    .apply(lambda r: shapely.geometry.Point(r["Lon"], r["Lat"]), axis=1)
    .values,
    crs="EPSG:4326",
)

gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=df2.loc[:, ["Lon", "Lat"]]
    .apply(lambda r: shapely.geometry.Point(r["Lon"], r["Lat"]), axis=1)
    .values,
    crs="EPSG:4326",
)

# add buffer to df1,  NB need to correctly use CRS systems to define distances
gdf1 = (
    gdf1.to_crs(gdf1.estimate_utm_crs()).geometry.buffer(MIN_DIST).to_crs("EPSG:4326")
)

# join data frames back together
df2_in_df1 = df2.reset_index().merge(
    gpd.sjoin(gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gdf1), gdf2, how="inner"),
    left_on="index",
    right_on="index_right",
)


# plot it to see what's been found
fig = (
    px.scatter_mapbox(df1, lat="Lat", lon="Lon")
    .update_traces(marker={"color": "red", "opacity":.3})
    .add_traces(px.scatter_mapbox(df2, lat="Lat", lon="Lon").update_traces(marker={"color":"red", "opacity":.3}).data)
    .add_traces(px.scatter_mapbox(df2_in_df1, lat="Lat", lon="Lon").update_traces(marker={"color":"green", "size":10}).data)

    )

fig.update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "open-street-map",
        "layers": [
            {
                "source": json.loads(gdf1.geometry.to_json()),
                "below": "traces",
                "type": "line",
                "color": "purple",
                "line": {"width": 1.5},
            }
        ],
    },
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
)
```

|  | index | Lon | Lat | Timestamp | index_right |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7 | 4.47 | 62.49 | 2021-04-28 00:18:00 | 7 |

[image]